# Man user name problem

Tags: permissions

I have a user on my Ubuntu 13.04 that his username is: me and his name is Man 
Also I do not know the difference between user name and his name (in User accounts he is displayed as:

```
    Man
    me
```

I have had no problem with this user until i decided to install truecrypt. 
After downloading "truecrypt-7.1a-linux-x64.tar.gz" and extracting it, a file is created with filename = truecrypt-7.1a-setup-x64
I tried to install truecrypt by running this file, but no success.
I tried sudo as well, but there was no success yet.
After running nautilus by sudo and looking at files permission tab, the permission was: -rw-------
and the owner was: "Man" but the group was "me"
tring to change the group permission of the file to "Read Only" results following error:

```
    **The owner could not be found**
    sorry, could not change the owner of "truecrypt-7.1a-setup-x64": Specified owner 'Man' doesn't exist
```

and nautilus is closed immediately 
Is there any one who could help me to:
1) understand the difference between the username (me) and his name (Man)
2) How to solve my problem in changing the permission of that file and installing truecrypt?

Comment: Please add screenshot of User Accounts instead of text description.

Answer (score 1):

If you will look in  `/etc/passwd` file (you can do this running `cat /etc/passwd` from [Using The Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal)), you will see a list of the system's accounts, giving for each account some useful information, including in your case, `me` (`Man`) user account.

The `/etc/passwd` contains one entry per line for each user (or user account, including `me`) of the system. All fields are separated by a colon (`:`) symbol. Total seven fields as follows:

1. **Username: It is used when user logs in. It should be between 1 and 32 characters in length** (in your case this field should be `me`).
2. Password: An x character indicates that encrypted password is stored in `/etc/shadow` file.
3. User ID (UID): Each user must be assigned a user ID (UID). UID 0 (zero) is reserved for root and UIDs 1-99 are reserved for other predefined accounts. Further UID 100-999 are reserved by system for administrative and system accounts/groups.
4. Group ID (GID): The primary group ID (stored in `/etc/group` file)
5. **User ID Info: The comment field.** It allow you to add extra information about the users such as **user's full name**, phone number etc (in your case this field should be something like `Man,,,`).
6. Home directory: The absolute path to the directory the user will be in when they log in. If this directory does not exists then users directory becomes `/`
7. Command/shell: The absolute path of a command or shell (`/bin/bash`). Typically, this is a shell. Please note that it does not have to be a shell.

Source: [Understanding /etc/passwd File Format](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/).

---

Now, regarding the second question, to change the user ownership to user `me` for `truecrypt-7.1a-linux-x64.tar.gz` file, run the following command in terminal:

```
sudo chown me:me truecrypt-7.1a-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

See `man chown` and `man chmod` for more info.

Comment: I used this command: sudo chown me:me truecrypt-7.1a-linux-x64.tar.gz, but in normal nautilus (not root) the owner is "Me" and in sudo nautilus the owner of the file is Man!!! and I can not change permissions with the same error as before